# Calling methods and returning values? Tic-tac-toe

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, tic-tac-toe

I'm having problems getting my displayWinner method to work. I believe my calls aren't working  in the way I think they should because I'm not very familiar with using multiple methods as this concept was only recently introduced.

The code is the following:

```
import java.util.*;
public class tic
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        boolean flag=false;

        char[][] board = 
        {
        {' ', ' ', ' '},
        {' ', ' ', ' '},
        {' ', ' ', ' '}
        };

        boolean done = false;
        int player = 1;
        int row = 0;
        int col = 0;

        while (flag != true) 
        {
          checkForWinner(board);
          System.out.println("Enter the row and column for your next move");
          row = in.nextInt();
          col = in.nextInt();
          if (player == 1) 
          {
            board[row][col] = 'X';
            player = 2;
            checkForWinner(board);
           }
          else 
          { 
            board[row][col] = 'O';
            player = 1;
            checkForWinner(board);
          }
          printBoard(board);
          checkForWinner(board);
        }

        displayWinner(player, flag);  


    }
    public static void printBoard(char[][] board) 
    {
    for (int row = 0; row < 3; row++) 
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < 3; col++) 
        {
            System.out.print("|" + board[row][col] + "|");
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("-------");
    }
    }
    public static boolean checkForWinner(char[][] board)
   {
       // checkForWinner() method determines if a pattern of data stored
       // in the 2 D char array indicates the a player has won the game.

        boolean flag = false;
        boolean flag1 = false;
        boolean flag2 = false;
        boolean flag3 = false;
        boolean flag4 = false;

        // checks the contents of each row for matching data   
        for (int i = 0; i <= 2; i++)
        {
            if ((board[i][0] == board[i][1] && board[i][1] == board[i][2]) && board[i][2] != ' ') 
                flag1 = true;
        }

         // checks the contents of each column for matching data
        for (int j = 0; j <= 2; j++)
        {
            if ((board[0][j] == board[1][j] && board[1][j] == board[2][j]) && board[2][j] != ' ') 
                flag2 = true;
        }

        // checks the contents of one diagonal for matching data
        if ((board[0][0] == board[1][1] && board[1][1] == board[2][2]) && board[2][2] != ' ') 
                flag3 = true;

        // checks the contents of the other diagonal for matching data
        if ((board[0][2] == board[1][1] && board[1][1] == board[2][0]) && board[2][0] != ' ') 
                flag4 = true;

        // checks if any of the previous conditions evaluated to true        
        if (flag1 == true || flag2 == true || flag3 == true || flag4 == true)
            flag = true;

       // returns true if a winner was found; returns false is no winner     
       return flag;
   } // end of checkForWinner method
   public static void displayWinner(int player, boolean flag)
   {

    if (flag == true)
    {
        int currentplayer;
        currentplayer=player;
        System.out.println("The winner of the game is" +currentplayer);
    }


   }
}
```

The displayWinner method is at the bottom and the while loop in the main method is the one that plays the game and gives each player their turn.

Edit: My question would be how do I pass the flag from the checkForWinner method to the displayWinner method so that it can print out who the winner of the game is?

Comment: What is your question? What is the way you think they should work and why?

Comment: You've yet to identify the source of your errors, and that's the first step that needs to be done before you can fix it. Use a debugger to help you do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not updating `flag` declared in your `main` method. Change each of

```
checkForWinner(board);
```

to

```
flag = checkForWinner(board);
```

Without this `flag` will never change and you will never leave your `while (flag != true)` (which could be simplified to `while(!flag)`) loop which means you will never execute `displayWinner(player, flag)` method.

Comment: After changing it and messing around with the if statements I managed to fix it. Thank you for your answer and this actually helped me understand how calling different methods work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the flag actually change you have `checkWinner(board);` when it should be `flag = checkWinner(board);` also you call the function twice (once at the beginning of the loop and once at the end) which there is no need for and you should take out the one at the beginning. Also your `checkWinner(board)` method won't work because it will return true if a row or column has the same char and at the beginning they all have the same char (' ') so it will register a win straight away, rather have it check whether a row or column matches one of the player chars.